# Non-integer conditional moment of exponential functional of Brownian motion

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, special-functions, martingales

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion.
I want to solve the following:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^1 e^{\sigma B_t}dt \right)^{1/(1-\beta) }\mid e^{\sigma B_1}=z \right],
$$
for some fixed $0<\beta<1$ and $\sigma>0$.

This type of integral is important in finance, for example, get the price of path-dependent options like [Asian option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_option).

**What I have tried.**

Yor (1992) have obtained the density as follows:
$$
  \mathbb{P}\left\{ \int_0^1 e^{\sigma B_t} dt=u \mid e^{\sigma W_1} = z \right\}
=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sigma}{u} \exp \left( \frac{(\log z)^2}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{2(1+z)}{\sigma^2 u} \right) \theta_{\frac{4\sqrt{z}}{\sigma^2 u}}\left(\frac{\sigma^2}{4} \right),
$$
where $\theta_r(s)$ is the (normalized) Hartman-Watson density characterized via its Laplace transform:
$$
  \int_0^{\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2 s \right) \theta_r(s)\,ds=I_{\alpha}(r),
$$
where $I_{\alpha}$ is the usual [modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1). We have also the  integral representation due to Marc Yor,
$$
  \theta_r(s) = \frac{r}{\sqrt{2\pi^3 s}} \int_0^{\infty} \exp\left(\frac{\pi^2-y^2}{2s}-r \cosh(y) \right)\sinh(y) \sin\left(\frac{\pi y}{s}\right)\,dy.
$$
Thus, I tried to find direct integration using Fubini's theorem as follows:
$$
  \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^1 e^{\sigma B_t}dt \right)^{1/(1-\beta) }\mid e^{\sigma B_1}=z \right] =\\
\frac{4\sqrt{z}}{\pi\sigma^2}\exp\left( \frac{(\log z)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\int_0^{\infty} \exp\left( \frac{\pi^2-y^2}{\sigma^2/2} \right) \sinh(y) \sin\left(\frac{\pi y}{\sigma^2 /4}\right) \int_0^{\infty} x^{-\frac{1}{1-\beta}} e^{-\left(\frac{2(1+z)}{\sigma^2}+\frac{4\sqrt{z}}{\sigma^2}\cosh(y)\right) x } \, dx \, dy \\
=\frac{4\sqrt{z}}{\pi\sigma^2}\exp\left( \frac{(\log z)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\int_0^{\infty} \exp\left( \frac{\pi^2-y^2}{\sigma^2/2} \right) \sinh(y) \sin\left(\frac{\pi y}{\sigma^2 /4}\right) \left(\frac{2(1+z)}{\sigma^2}+\frac{4\sqrt{z}}{\sigma^2}\cosh(y)\right)^{\frac{\beta}{1-\beta}} \Gamma\left(-\frac{\beta}{1-\beta}\right) \, dy,
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).
But the gamma function can not be defined on the negative real values, hence this integral may not give a correct answer.
So is there alternative approach to find the conditional moment?

Thanks.